# Multiply 2 input values and display on input textbox using Meteor template helper

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm developing restaurant management system using MeteorJS. What I try to accomplish here is when I type in some number on "Quantity" column it multiples itself with the price in "Price" column, then displays total sales inside textbox in "Total" column. I'm aware that there're several solutions out there but I wonder if this can be done using Meteor template helpers.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN9lJ.png)

Comment: Closing as too board: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can, Meteor template is reactive so you simply need to do something like:

```
<template name="costCalcualtor">
  <input id="quantity">
  <p id="price">$10</p>
  <p>It'd be ${{totalCost}}.</p>
</template>
```

in your html, and in your JS, simply makes a `Template.costCalcualtor` event that fires every time user finish typing in the `input` of "quantity" id, parse the innerHTML as integer, multiply it by the price (another integer obtained by parsing innerHTML of the `p` of "price" id), `Session.set('price',finalValue`), then have `totalCost` as a `Template.costCalcualtor` helper function that returns a new value based on `Session.get("price")`.

Update:

1. don't just return a variable in the keyup event, you should use `Session.set("total", price*quantity);` in the end, and the line `var total = parseInt($('total').val(price * quantity));` doesn't really do anything.
2. then you need `{{totalCost}}` in the template. and define a helper to retrieve the value of the session variable "total": `Session.get("total")`.

Here is a walk-through to demonstrate what I mean:

in your `.js` fileh:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);
  Template.salesAdd.helpers({
    total: function(){
      return Session.get("total")
    }
  });
  Template.salesAdd.events({ 'keyup #meow': function() { 
    var quantity = parseInt($('#meow').val()); 
    console.log(quantity); 
    Session.set("total", quantity); } })
}
```

in your `.html` file:

```
<head>
  <title>meow</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> salesAdd}}
</body>

<template name="salesAdd">
   <input id="meow">
   <p> What you've typed: {{total}}</p>
</template>
```

run it & see the number changes as you type in `<input>`.

Meteor is very a powerful tool developed by great people, and what is nice about it is that it is easy-to-learn and it has good documentation, so I suggest you to [go through the basic docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/defining-templates) and if possible, [the full api](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my code 

`<template name="salesAdd">
 ...
<input type="number" name="price" id="price">
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" >
<input type="number" name="total" id="total" value="total" >
</template>`

`Template.salesAdd.events({
    'keyup #quantity': function() {
        
        var quantity = parseInt($('quantity').val());
        
        var price = parseInt($('price').val());
        
        var total = parseInt($('total').val(price * quantity));      
        
        return total;      
    }
});`

Comment: so sorry I dont know how to edit the code format. I try to get input data from input form when user enter in "quantity" field. It doesn't seems to work. What I'm I missing here? Thank you a again for your patient. I'm getting there.

Comment: Never mind. I got it. Forgot #. Thank you so much for this

Comment: @user3080456 You are almost there, I've just updated my question regarding that.